# JavaScript use 1 forEach to loop 2 arrays to apply same function

Tags: javascript, frontend

New to javaScript. I have 2 arrays use forEach function to apply the same function:

```
<script>
    const selectors=document.querySelectorAll("#customer-table > select ")
    const inputs=document.querySelectorAll("#customer-table > input")
    
    selectors.forEach((selector) => {
      selector.onchange = function() {myFunction()};
    })
    
    inputs.forEach((input) => {
      input.onchange = function() {myFunction()};
    })

    function myFunction() {
      $('#customer-table').submit();
    }
    </script>
```

Is there anyway I can combine the 2 forEach functions into one?

Comment: Create a function that you can pass the array you want to foreach

Comment: OR so `cssSelectors.forEach(cssSelector => document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector).forEach(e => e.onChange = myFunction)))`

Comment: `const allInputs=document.querySelectorAll("#customer-table > select, #customer-table > input")`

Comment: I'd suggest `allInputs = document.querySelectorAll("#customer-table > :is(select, input)")`, and then use only the one `forEach()`.